# Would the service socket be closed before core dump or after it?

Tags: linux, sockets, coredump

If a service crashes and generates a core dump, will the socket which the service listens be closed immediately or closed when the core dump is done?

Comment: Why does that matters to you? The dumping of a core file is an atomic operation (during which nothing can happens inside the application), which generally is very quick. So both cases are observationally equivalent IMHO.

Comment: It is not always very quick, in my server, it takes 15 mins to core dump a 46G process

Comment: But still, the application cannot do anything why the core dump happens. File descriptors state cannot change during that dump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I see in my application is that a listening socket is not closed when a signal arrives and Linux starts writing a core file. It is only closed when the core file has been written.

In order to change this behavior it is possible to close a listening socket right in a signal handler. `close()` is async-signal-safe: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html

Comment: thx, I verified it with strace and it is actually no close socket syscall after the process got the core dump signal